# Golang daemon with goroutines won't stop executing

Tags: multithreading, go, daemon, background-process, goroutine

I've created a daemon that has the goal to consume queues in parallel. To test if it keeps executing in the background I've implemented a function that creates a file every 10 seconds until it reaches X, where X is the highest number of processes that I configured for the queues. The parameters for the queues are defined on the config.yaml file.

The problem now is that even though I stop and remove the daemon, it seems that the program keeps running and creating files... I've tried building and running the program again, exiting it, ending the processes, deleting the files, but nothing seems to work, files keep being created on the program directory.

You can check the program code [here](https://gist.github.com/SandroSimes/f8f18ccad22e68693b76457b5cea772e), and the config file [here](https://gist.github.com/SandroSimes/5a6fb31c5e591107c5d4b39345c92819). 
Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will never exit until it does processing for `len(queues)` times. It is not a concurrent code - all in main body - and there is no signal to tell the code to stop. The problem is here:

```
case "run":
    // Installing the service
    installed, err := service.Install()
    logError(err, installed)
    // Starting the service
    started, err := service.Start()
    logError(err, started)
    if err == nil {
        // Creating a goroutine and executing the queue's processes in parallel
        for i := 0; i < len(queues); i++ {
            go startProcessing(queues[i])
            time.Sleep(time.Second) // Waiting for other functions to execute
        }
        select {} // To prevent the goroutine from exiting the main func
    }
    fmt.Println(started)
```

As it can be seen the `select{}` line will sit there and run for ever! :) It is better to move this case clauses, into their's own goroutines and have a quit signal there like this:

```
select {
    case <-quit:
        return
}
```

Though this is not the cleanest way to handle start/stop in Go apps; it just shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When asking questions like this you should consider putting together a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

That way, since the problem size is a lot smaller, you might figure out the problem on your own.
If not, at least the people here will have an easier time helping you.